A worker VM in more than one azure automation account hybrid worker group?
I've seen posts and documentation saying that the node to hybrid worker group relationship is one-to-one, but I've managed one-to-two. I actually didn't know about the one-to-one limitation and thought it could be one-to-many, but noticed I couldn't go beyond one-to-two. This is all done via the azure portal and no scripting.

automation_account_01

workgroup_01

vm01
vm02




automation_account_02

workgroup_02

vm01
vm02





So I have two automation accounts with a hybrid worker group each. Each group have the same two associated worker nodes, which goes against the supposed limitation. If I try to add nodes to a third automation account's hybrid worker group, those two worker nodes are not visible to choose from.
So either I found a bug or the limitation is changed to one-to-two.

You can't register the hybrid worker across multiple Automation accounts. A hybrid worker can only listen for jobs from a single Automation account. Check the Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker#how-does-it-work for more details
